# having trouble formatting if-else statement in python

Tags: python

My program finds the roots using newton's algorithm. I am having trouble with a last part when if there is not enough iterations to find the root to print that the root has not been found.

```
for i in range(N):
    f= evaluate(p,deg,x0)
    s=evaluate(d,deg-1,x0)
    if s==0:
        print "Can't divide by 0"
        return -1
    x1=x0 - f/s
    print ("Iteration %d" %(i+1))
    print "%f" %x0
    if abs(x1-x0)<tol:
        print "Found a root %f" %x1
        return 0
    else:
        x0=x1
    if abs(x1-x0)>tol:
       print "root not found"
```

somehow it seems to skip the last if statement and doesn't print anything, i tried to put it in different places. when i placed it before the previous if-statement then it skips the x0=x1 part. Im confused of whats wrong with it.

N is the number of iterations, x0 is the initial guess

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a Stack Overflow issue or if this is exactly how your code looks to Python, but I think your indentation is incorrect... EDIT: It looks correct now

Comment: @Dream: That's the beauty of putting Python code into Stack Overflow; because it formats _differently_, some problems that are difficult to spot in a local editor are sometimes glaringly obvious when rendered here. This code is broken, and obviously so, thanks to the different formatting. :)

Comment: thats how the code looks

Comment: At least in the `vim` and derived text editors, you will find the `:set list` mode extremely helpful for telling the difference between spaces and tabs. Python cares, so you have to care too.

Comment: aside from indentation, you have the problem with x0=x1.  It appears like abs(x1-x0)>tol will never be true because x0=x1. Edit: Perhaps the last if should not be indented?

Comment: oo but where should i put it since i want to change the values of x0 to x1 every time it iterates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not correct for displaying that a root is not found. You do not want to check that `abs(x0 - x1) > tol`, because this is not relevant for finding a root. Think about it: the difference could be very large between `x0` and `x1` but you could still be on the right track to finding the root. You wouldn't want to jump out of the iterations just because `x1` is different than `x0` on *some* iteration.

A better thing would simply be to place the error statement outside of the `for` loop, such as:

```
for i in range(N):
    f = evaluate(p,deg,x0)
    s = evaluate(d,deg-1,x0)

    if s==0:
        print "Can't divide by 0"
        return -1
    x1=x0 - f/s
    print ("Iteration %d" %(i+1))
    print "%f" %x0
    if abs(x1-x0)<tol:
        print "Found a root %f" %x1
        return 0
    else:
        x0=x1

# If we exhaust the for-loop without returning due to
# a found root, then there must have been an error with
# convergence, so just print that at exit.
print "Error: did not converge to the root in %d iterations."%(N)
print "Check your initial guess and check your functions for cyclic points."
```

Comment: As another suggested tip, it's often helpful to diagnose problems with iterative solvers if you save the sequence of `x` values. So you might start by creating a list `x_vals = [0.0]*(N+1)` which gives you a length N+1 list of zeros. Then set `x_vals[0]` to the initial guess, and add the result of iteration `i` into the slot `x_vals[i]`, for `i` in `range(1,N)`. At each iteration, you'd reference the previous value with `x_vals[i-1]`. This lets you match the usual textbook notation better, and for diagnostic purposes you can return the whole list of `x` values rather than just the final one.

Comment: And even better is to use NumPy arrays and operations once you get around to learning NumPy.

Comment: This `print ("Iteration %d" % (i+1))` should be `print "Iteration %d" % i+1`

Comment: @burhan, no it is correct as is. You can call `print` like it is a function, even in older versions of Python. In Python 3k you *must* call it this way, but you still have the *option* to call it this way in older versions.

Comment: You are right @EMS, my point was its best to be consistent, choose either one or the other. Ideally stick with the "function call" syntax so one less thing to worry about when 3K comes full swing.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, not having done anything with Newton's method in forever, that what you want is something more like:

```
x1 = sys.maxint # the first iteration is a throw-away
                # you could do this a different way, but you have a lot of global 
                # variables that I don't know how to handle.
for i in range(N):
    # ....
    if abs(x1-x0)<tol:
        # ...

    # you want these two lines together, somehow.
    x0 = x1
    x1 = x0 - f/s

    #...
    # no "else" down here

# no "if abs(x1-x0)>tol:", because it's taken care of by the return(0)
# earlier. Also note the unindent.
print "root not found"
```